# assign tableview cell data to textfield using didselectRowAtIndex

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.2

Iam having a UItableview when we click on one cell i want to get the data in cell and must assign to UIlabel in another controller and display it .like that i want to do it for all the cells in tableview

In that controller i have an UIlabel i want to update the cell data to that.

can any one help me am new to this

```
(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];    
           }
    cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Companydetails *details1= [[Companydetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"Companydetails" bundle:nil];
    details1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:details1 animated:NO];
    [details1 release]; 
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


}
```

Comment: I've been starring at this question for 2 minutes now, yet I couldn't grasp where its Xcode-related part is. Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In your second view controller create a property of UITextField Like :

```
.h file
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITextField *txtField;

.m file
@synthesize txtField;
```

Now in you current class from where you want to present that view controller set value of UITextField of second view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Companydetails *details1= [[Companydetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"Companydetails" bundle:nil];
    details1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    details1.txtField.text = cell.textLabel.text. 
    [self presentModalViewController:details1 animated:NO];
    [details1 release]; 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in SeconView.h

```
NSString *passValue;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *passValue;
```

In SecondView.m

```
@synthesize passValue;
```

In FirstView.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Companydetails *details1= [[Companydetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"Companydetails" bundle:nil];
    details1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
details1.passValue=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self presentModalViewController:details1 animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Set this passvalue string on label text in didload method in SecondView.m